Como dezplazar valores de un vector sin alterar el orden del vector
Buenas estoy haciendo un programa en java y este es el enunciado
Cargar un vector de 5 elementos, luego pedir un nuevo elemento, pedir en que posicion quiere poner el elemento,
en vez de reemplazar debe correr el elemento de la casilla para la siguiente posicion
2 archivos Main y Taller 19, en taller 19 habra 3 metodos, leer procesar e imprimir, y en el main el ciclo de repeticion
mi problema es que por ejemplo, cuando ingreso un vector de 3 espacios con los valores 1,2, 3 y quiero que el nuevo valor se almacene en la posicion 2 y con el valor 9 deberia salir  [1,9,2,3] pero sale [0,9,2,3].
Me podrian señalar mi error o lo que esta mal? aqui les proporciono mi avance, son 2 archivos main
    package Taller_19;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Taller_19 {

    public static void leer() {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de elementos del vector:"));
        int[] vector = new int[n];

        

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            vector[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el elemento " + (i + 1) + ":"));
        }
    

        procesar(vector);
    }

    public static void procesar(int[] vector) {
        int posicion;
        int nuevoValor;

        do {
            posicion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la posicion a modificar (1-" + vector.length + "):"));
            if (posicion < 1 || posicion > vector.length) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Posicion invalida. El valor debe estar entre 1 y " + vector.length);
            }
        } while (posicion < 1 || posicion > vector.length);

        nuevoValor = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nuevo valor:"));

        int[] nuevoVector = new int[vector.length + 1];

        for (int i = vector.length; i > posicion - 1; i--) {
            nuevoVector[i] = vector[i - 1];
        }

        nuevoVector[posicion - 1] = nuevoValor;

        Main.imprimir(vector, nuevoVector, nuevoValor);
    }
}

y este de aqui es el Main principal
package Taller_19;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String continuar;

        do {
            Taller_19.leer();
            continuar = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Desea continuar? (s/n)").toLowerCase();
        } while (continuar.equals("s"));
    }

    public static void imprimir(int[] vector, int[] nuevoVector, int nuevoValor) {
        String resultado = "S A L I D A\nTamaño del vector: " + vector.length + "\nVector original: [";
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            resultado += vector[i];
            if (i < vector.length - 1) {
                resultado += ", ";
            }
        }
        resultado += "]\nValor ingresado: " + nuevoValor + "\nNuevo Vector: [";
        for (int i = 0; i < nuevoVector.length; i++) {
            resultado += nuevoVector[i];
            if (i < nuevoVector.length - 1) {
                resultado += ", ";
            }
        }
        resultado += "]\n";

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resultado);
    }
}


Como complemento a la respuesta ya aportada por Cesar y para clarificar un poco lo que quiere decir.
Lo primero indicarte que como sabrás las posiciones en los arrays en Java se numeran empezando por cero. No sé si numerarlas al introducir la posición empezando por 1 en tu caso es un requisito, pero como habrás observado, añade un poco más de dificultad a la hora de comprender qué hace el programa.
Según tu descripción y tu código para añadir un elemento lo que haces es crear una copia del vector existente. El problema está en que has olvidado copiar los valores que están antes de la posición seleccionada. Todos esos valores se deben copiar en la misma posición en el nuevo vector.
Distinguiremos tres partes en la copia:

Valores ANTES de posición seleccionada
Valor asociado a la
posición seleccionada
Valores que aparecen DESPUES de la
posición seleccionada

Teniendo esto claro, podemos reestructurar y completar un poco la parte de tu código que realiza la copia y la inserción
    int[] nuevoVector = new int[vector.length + 1];
 
    // ANTES
    for (int i = 0; i < (posicion - 1); i++) {
        nuevoVector[i] = vector[i];
    }
    
    // POSICION SELECCIONADA
    nuevoVector[posicion - 1] = nuevoValor;
    
    // DESPUES
    for (int i = (posicion - 1); i < vector.length; i++) {
        nuevoVector[i + 1] = vector[i];
    }

Si omitimos la parte ANTES, si no lo hacemos, Java te dejará esas posiciones con el valor por defecto de los enteros [int], que es el cero, de ahí que obtengas ese extraño resultado.

Tu error esta en que cuento llegas a la posición en la que deseas insertar el nuevo numero, paras, lo insertas y no sigues insertando el resto de numero del vector, te imprime 0, porque aunque al vector no le hayas insertado ningún valor, internamente estos tiene un valor de 0 en todas las posiciones, a menos que los cambies.
Lo que deberías hacer es no parar el ciclo, inserta como lo estas haciendo, y cuando llegue a la posición en la que vas a insertar el nuevo numero, pon una condición para que lo haga, pero no te detengas ahí, para que siga insertando el resto de números y no te imprima 0.
